# Loop to repeatedly square an input turn output to zero after a few runs, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: java, loops

I wrote this loop to continue squaring a number until it surpasses 1000000.

```
while(n<1000000){
  n=n*n;
  System.out.println(n);
  count++;
}
```

however when I input a 2 it will do the first 4 squares correctly and then output zero infinitly. i have no idea why as i am new to programming and would love some help.

Comment: If you input `2`, it will print `4`, `16`, `256`, `65536`, `0`, ... What is `65536 * 65536`? `4,294,967,296`. What is max value for an `int`? `2,147,483,647`. The `int` value overflowed, and happens to overflow to a `0` value. *Solution:* Change `n` to `long`, so it can handle `999,999 * 999,999 = 999,998,000,001` without overflowing.

Comment: You'll have to change the type.

Comment: If you use `long` instead of `int`, you can go up to `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`. You can afford one more step.

Answer (score 1):

The maximal value of an int is 2147483647. The result of 65536*65536 will overflow to 0. Afterwards you are only multiplying 0*0 forever.

Have a look at the [Java spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2) to find out more about the possible values for primitive types:

**4.2.1. Integral Types and Values**

> The values of the integral types are integers in the following ranges:
>
> - For byte, from -128 to 127, inclusive
> - For short, from -32768 to 32767, inclusive
> - For int, from -2147483648 to 2147483647, inclusive
> - For long, from -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807, inclusive
> - For char, from '\u0000' to '\uffff' inclusive, that is, from 0 to 65535

Edit: As described by Andreas in his comment, if you use long it will work.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to integer overflow.

since you are doing n = n* n, it is squaring the previous number.
for eg if n = 2 to begin with,
loop 1: 
   n = 2 * 2 = 4;
loop 2:
   n = 4 * 4 = 8;
loop 3:
   n = 8 * 8 = 64;
...
loop k: 
   n = 2^k * 2^k = 2^2k

its going to overflow the storage capacity of an integer which is 2147483647 after a few iterations.

after 4 iterations you are calculation
2^32 which is 4294967296.
This causes n to be assigned to be 0 because in java integer overflow is handled by assigning to 0.
It remains 0 after that and continues infinitely as it never meets the termination condition.

Comment: This is not correct because the minimum possible value of an int is  -2147483648.

Comment: thanks for the correction, I meant to suggest that it gets assigned to 0 after overflow. 0 is not the minimum possible value. I will make the edit.